# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 5.5 workbench

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Cuando ejecuto la clase Prueba01 aparece el siguiente error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='CLIENTE'' at line 1

## ContadorModel

```
package model;
import accesobd.AccesoBD;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class ContadorModel {

    public static String getContador(String nombreTabla) throws Exception {

        Connection cn=AccesoBD.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps= null;
        ResultSet rs= null;
        String contador= null;

        String sql= "Select right(concat(repeat('0', int_contlongitud)," +
                "int_contitem),int_contlongitud) as item from contador" +
                "where vch_conttabla = ?";

        ps=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        nombreTabla = nombreTabla.toUpperCase();
        ps.setString(1, nombreTabla);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();

        if(!rs.next()){
            return contador;
        }

        contador = rs.getString("item");

        sql="update contador" +
        "set int_contitem= int_contitem +1"+
                "where vch_conttabla= ?";
        ps=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, nombreTabla);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        rs.close();
        ps.close();

        return contador;
    }//getContador
}//Contador model
```

## Prueba01

Yo use CounterModel.getContent ("cliente") en donde coloque cliente para tener como item 00021.

Muestro el query que sale correcto en Workbench
Select right(concat(repeat('0', int_contlongitud),int_contitem), int_contlongitud) as item from contador where vch_conttabla ='cliente'

```
package Pruebas;
import model.ContadorModel;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Prueba01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            System.out.println(ContadorModel.getContador("cliente"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Prueba01.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}
}
```

Favor alguien que me ayude a ver cual es mi error, porque me dice que cliente esta mal y no entiendo mucho.

## Tabla contador

[image: Tabla contador]

Comment: Pero, ¿cuál es el nombre de tu cliente?

Comment: La tabla en si es contador, el cual contiene en vch_conttabla todas las tablas que tengo como cliente, empleado, moneda, por eso dice nombretabla en getContador(String nombreTabla), por ejemplo en vez de cliente también puedo colocar empleado.

Comment: Tenes un error al armar el query, falta un espacio entre contador y where.. el query te esta quedando from contadorwhere.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y la proxima vez pon un titulo mas descriptivo por favor.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración y la ayuda :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primera viste observo que al con catenaria las consultas no dejas espacios. Por ejemplo en la tabla contador el resultado de la concatenacion tendría contadorwhere junto.

Debes dejar espacios. Puede imprimir en consola la consulta  y ejecutarla en el manejador de base de datos 0
Para comprobarla.

Comment: Gracias :) ya lo corregi.

Comment: Sergio, en general las preguntas con errores tipograficos son cerradas y se le aclara a OP en un comentario, ya que no ayudan a futuros usuarios.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario.